# Only show certain items in a mysql database using php and time()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way to only show the items that are older than a certain date in a php mysql array?  I'm using this query method and sorting by lastpost_cl:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM properties ORDER BY lastpost_cl";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
mysql_close();
```

and I was thinking the way of checking the time would be:

```
if (time() <= strtotime($lastpost_cl)) {

}
```

How can I combine the two and only show lastpost_cl that are older that the current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM properties WHERE lastpost_cl < NOW() ".
    "ORDER BY lastpost_cl";
```

This assumes you're storing the date using one of mysql date types. See the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can do that on its own. Just change your query to this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM properties WHERE lastpost_cl < NOW() ORDER BY lastpost_cl";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the sql query though, because the time on the sql server and web server could be different. A query like this would get everything older than a week

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM properties
where lastpost_cl < now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
ORDER BY lastpost_cl
```